# Possible order of an element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $a$ belong to $G$. If the element $aH$ has order $3$ in the group $G/H$ and $|H| = 10$, what are the possibilities for the order of $a$?

**Doubt -**

1) $|aH|$ has order $10$ in $G$ . I am not able to get a clear picture of what is meant by order $3$ in $G/H$.

I think $|aH|$ can means two things . It can represent size of the the set. And it can also represent order of element $aH$ in $G/H$.

2) $|G|= |aH| *|H|$. Is this right?

Since order of $aH$ must divides $|a|$, 
$|a|$ must be multiple of $3$.

Also $a^3H = H$, which implies $a^3$ lies in $H$.

By Lagrange's theorem, $|a^3|$ can be $1,2,5$ or $10$.

$|a| = |a^3| * GCD(|a|,3)$

Is this right till here?

How to proceed after this?

Any hint or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: "The **element** (not set) $aH$ has order 3 in the **group** (not set) $G/H$"

Comment: It's quite clear that it is not talking about the cardinality of the set $aH$

Comment: You're deepening your confusion between order and cardinality by using the same notation for the two. It's unusual to use vertical bars to denote the order of a group element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$G/H$" means to take the group $G$ and parititon it into pieces *congruent* to $H$.  This means more than "piece of size $H$", each piece is a translated copy of each other piece.  One piece is $eH = \{e h \mid h \in H\}$.  The other pieces are constructed by left-multiplying $H$ by elements of $G$.  Each $gH$ is a congruent copy of $H$ and the collection of $\{gH \mid g \in G\}$ is all of the congruent pieces, usually with many repetitions.  Suppose $g \in H$, then since $H$ is a group (closed under multiplication), for each $h \in H$, $g h \in H$, so $gH = H = eH$, that is, the congruent copy of $H$ made by (left-)multiplying by an element of $H$ is the same (coset) as $eH$.

1) "$|aH|$" does not appear in the problem statement so you are choosing to confuse yourself by using it.  Since $aH$ *as written* is not an element of a group, the vertical bars mean "size as a set".  To clarify this to any reader (including yourself), recall that the purpose of notation is to clarify your meaning, so establish your semantics before using the notation: "In $G/H$, the coset $aH$ has order $|aH| = 3$ ..." or "The set has cardinality $|aH| = 10$ ...".

"$aH$ has order $3$ in the group $G/H$" means that $aH$, $(aH)^2$, and $(aH)^3$ are all different and the last one is $eH$.  That is, we have listed three different congruent copies of $H$, the last one of which is $eH$.  However, we have a convenience, since $H$ is normal in $G$ (necessary condition for the quotient $G/H$ to be a group), 
$$  (aH)^2 = aHaH = aaHH = a^2H  \text{,}  $$
where we have used that $H$ is normal to swap $Ha$ to $aH$ and then that $H$ is a group to observe that the product of any two elements of $H$ is an element of $H$ (i.e., $HH = H$).  Applying the same argument to $(aH)^3 = a^3H = eH$, it must be the case that $a,a^2 \not\in H$ and $a^3 \in H$.  So we know that $G$ contains *at least* three distinct cosets (congruent copies) of $H$.  There could be more, but powers of $a$ cannot tell us about them.

2) We would only have $|G| = |H| \cdot |aH|$ if the powers of $aH$ included all the cosets of $H$ in $G$, but we don't have enough information to claim this.  The powers of $aH$ give us three cosets, but there could be more.  Another way to say this is that we do not know $G/H$ is cyclic, generated by $aH$.  Consider $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ under addition.  This group *is* cyclic (generated by each odd element), but if we pick $a = 4$, $a$ has order $2$ so does not generate this group.  Our choice of $a$ in the problem statement could be equally under-informative.

You would be able to apply Lagrange's theorem to the order of $a$ as an element of the group $H$ if $a$ were an element of $H$.  But it isn't; we already know $a$ and $a^2$ are not elements of $H$, so Lagrange's theorem does not apply.  Lagrange's theorem tells you that $|H|$ divides $|G|$, so $|G|$ is a multiple of $10$.  By other means (for instance, the first isomorphism theorem, which you may not have in your toolbox yet), you know the order of $aH$ in $G/H$ divides the order of $a$ in $G$ and the order of $a$ is the cardinality of the cyclic group generated by $a$ (BTW: This last equivalence is the source of the re-use of the vertical bar notation for order of an element.  Although "$|\langle a \rangle |$" would be more accurate, no one writes that.) so Lagrange's theorem tells you $3 \mid |G|$.  Putting these together, $\mathrm{lcm}(3,10) = 30$ divides the order of $G$.  That's as far as Lagrange's theorem speaks to this problem.

Perhaps a better, elementary, way to attack this problem is this.  Consider the list of distinct powers of $a$ (in $G$):
$$  \underline{e}, a, a^2, \underline{a^3}, a^4, a^5, \underline{a^6}, \dots  \text{.}  $$
(I've explicitly shown the first seven powers of $a$, but we do not know that these seven are distinct -- we only know the first three are distinct.)  We know that $a^3 \in H$, so the underlined elements must be distinct elements of $H$.  Since there are only $10$ elements of $H$, the pigeonhole principle tells us there can be only up to $10$ underlined powers of $a$ on this list and there could easily be fewer.

Comment: I think order of a can be only 1,3,6,15 and 30

Comment: Orders are 3,6,15 and 30 i think.

Comment: I read all three isomorphism theorem last night. Is there any way we can use that theorem to solve this ?

Comment: The order of $a$ cannot be $1$.  You already know $e \neq a \neq a^2 \neq e$.  Why can the order of $a$ not be $9$?  Could not $G \cong H \times \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ be $(1_H, g_{\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}})$, where $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$?  What makes you think you know *anything* about how many cosets of $H$ there are (beyond "a multiple of $3$")?

Comment: @EricTowers The order of $a$ cannot be $9$ since $a^3 \in H$, hence $|a^3| \bigm| |H| = 10$.

Comment: @Leppala : I agree.  But why wouldn't blue boy ever tell me that?  (I set up the most ridiculous example with $a$ having the wrong order...)